# Can I define a function/macro in emacs named .?

Tags: functions

I would like to define this function:

```
(defun . (object method &rest args)
 (apply (plist-get object method) args))
```

But, not surprisingly I get: if: Dot in wrong context

Not surprising because it looks like a cons cell and isn't. I can use some other character like @ or function name like dot, but it seems like it should be possible to use . too. Is there any way to do something like that?

The application is for a closure that defines a plist of functions, and I want something like a dot notation to access them.

This does work, but the double dot is a little unconventional from what I am used to:

```
(setq c (let ((counter 0))
      (list :inc (lambda (&optional dx)
               "Increment counter by DX (default=1)."
               (incf counter (or dx 1))))))


(defun .. (object method &rest args)
  (apply (plist-get object method) args))

(.. c :inc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```el
(defun \. (&optional n)
  "This is Lisp function `.'.
It just invokes`forward-char`."
  (interactive "p")
  (forward-char n))
```

`C-h f .` tells you about it.

`M-x . RET` invokes it interactively.

`(\. 42)` and `(\.)` invoke it from Lisp.

As you can see, you need to escape the `.` (with a backslash) when using the function name in Lisp.

Comment: Enabler!  Now we're going to have a "backslash-dot" library!

Comment: Hope not. It was already misguided (IMHO) to use just `-` as a library prefix. Too clever by half. ;-)

Comment: This didn't work for me in emacs 25.1.1, I still get the wrong dot context error. Is there anything special needed to make it work?

Comment: @JohnKitchin Works for me in 25.1.1.  Have the backslash in both places (definition and invocation)?

Comment: Hm. it does work in a clean emacs... Thanks for confirming.

Comment: It works with a clean emacs for some reason. I use C-x C-e at the end of the defun.

I am accepting this answer because it is simpler to make the function.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: You can define a function named `.` but it does not help you much.
The problem is not that you cannot define a function named `.` but that the evaluation of such a function is rather complicated.

```el
(eval
 '(setq c (let ((counter 0))
        (list :inc (lambda (&optional dx)
             "Increment counter by DX (default=1)."
             (incf counter (or dx 1))))))
 t)

(fset (intern ".") (lambda (object method &rest args)
             (apply (plist-get object method) args)))

;;; Evaluation of the function named `.':
(funcall (intern ".") c :inc)
```

You cannot evaluate it as `(. c :inc)` because you get the "dot in wrong context"-error.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like the version below also works with this: (\. c :inc). I guess if it takes an escape to do it, then .. doesn't seem so bad!